# ElasticsearchのRiverプラグインで定期的にMySQLからデータ取り込みすると重複する

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

ElasticsearchのRiverプラグインを使って定期的にMySQLからデータを取得したいと考えています。
基本的にデータはMySQLに保存し、検索のみElasticsearchから取得するのが目的です。
scheduleパラメータを使うと定期的にMySQLとコネクションするそうなので1時間ごとにMySQLと同期したいのですが、２回目以降の取得でデータが随時追加されていってしまいます。

例えば、articlesテーブルに10件しかデータがない場合、初回の取り込みは10件ですが、１時間後に２回目の取り込みをすると重複してるにも関わらずさらに10件取得してしまい、Elasticsearch側には20件ドキュメントが存在してしまいます。
常にMySQLのレコード数と同期を取りたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

以下MySQLからデータを取り込む設定です。

```
 {
   "type" : "jdbc",
   "jdbc" : {
      "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog_name",
      "user" : "root",
      "password" : "password",
      "schedule" : "0 0 0-23 ? * *",
      "sql" : "select * from articles",
      "index" : "blog_name",
      "type" : "articles"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDの指定がないためだと思います。

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#how-to-fetch-a-table
こちらに記載があります。
"If no _id column name is given, IDs will be automatically generated."

_idというカラム名（エイリアスでいいかと）をselectに追加するとうまくいくかと思います。

P.S.
残念ながら、Riverの機能は現在、非推奨になってしまいました。
https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers
長期的な観点では、別の手段も検討されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 重複せずにデータを取り込むことができました。ありがとうございます。
Riverが非推奨になったとのことですが、他の代替手段には何があるのでしょうか。

Comment: このツールの場合だと、Feederという使い方をするのが選択肢の一つかと。
https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#how-to-run-a-standalone-jdbc-feeder
外部のJavaプロセスとして起動する形になるようです。

あとは、fluentdとかlogstashというツールも選択肢の一つかと。